# unexpected result while communicating with another process's stdin

Tags: java, python, bash, pipe, ipc

My project directory has the 3 files below.

**rndbet/rndbet.py**

```
while True:
    s = input()
    if s == "exit":
        exit()
    else:
        print("I'm rndbet: " + s)
```

**rndbet/start**

```
python3 rndbet.py
```

**mjhd.java**

```
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class mjhd {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Process process = new ProcessBuilder("bash", "-c", "cd rndbet&&./start").start();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Scanner in = new Scanner(process.getInputStream());
                while (in.hasNextLine()) {
                    System.out.println("<- rndbet: " + in.nextLine());
                }
            }
        }).start();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        PrintStream out = new PrintStream(process.getOutputStream(), true);
        while (true) {
            out.println(in.nextLine());
        } //this part is actually broken; it shouldn't be an infinite loop
          //just for testing
    }
}
```

When I type `bash -c "cd rndbet&&./start"` directly from the command line, below happens.

```
$ bash -c "cd rndbet&&./start"
hi
I'm rndbet: hi
exit
```

But running the java program behaves differently.

```
$ java mjhd
hi
<- rndbet: I'm rndbet: hi
exit
<- rndbet: I'm rndbet: exit
exit
<- rndbet: I'm rndbet: exit
```

So now the Python script doesn't get the `exit` command correctly. Please help me fix this problem.

---

I've just found a problem that when the Python script is run via Java, an extra character of ASCII value 13 is always appended at the end of the sent text. What is a possible fix?

Comment: The issue is Both `PrintStream` and anonymous thread running and therefore the output messed up. why dont you put your `PrintStream` into the anonymous `Thread` and print out the lines?

Comment: @haifzhan The `PrintStream` doesn't print out anything in my code; it rather 'sends'.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found a simple answer.

Changing `out.println(in.nextLine());` to `out.print(in.nextLine() + '\n')` works.